# if else condition 'else' with select method is not working

Tags: loops

I need help:
This is a dropdown, my requirement is: if A is selected then select B if B is selected then select C if C is selected then select A. below is my code but its not working !!!

```
string=driver.findElement(By.id("JOBId"));
string=(VisibleText==("Mark JOB"));
//WebElement tmp = Select.getFirstSelectedOption();
//VisibleText = tmp.getText();


if (VisibleText==("Mark JOB")) {
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("GOBId"))).selectByVisibleText(" Larry JOB 
}       
    else if (VisibleText == "  Larry JOB "){
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("JOBId"))).selectByVisibleText(" Kevin JOB");   
}   
else if (VisibleText == " Kevin JOB ")
{
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("JOBId "))).selectByVisibleText(" Mark JOB");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Different initial JOB selected than expected");
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done already? And please tag the language.

Comment: "GOBId"; incomplete lines, string literals; wrong indentation; sometimes 1 space other times 2 spaces in string literals; "enter code here"??? well, with that amount of "caution" no compiler will be able to deal with that code (maybe a compiler for [whitespace programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)))